# Executing a command in SQL Server 2012 from VBScript

Tags: sql, sql-server, vbscript, command, execute

My company has a client that registers users for events by sending us an excel spreadsheet containing four fields - name, email, phone, and role.  I have written a VB script that converts the file into CSV, then parses that CSV.  On each line, I check to see if more than four elements are returned (Sometimes names include a title or something) and then I do a replace in a variable called SQL.  SQL is the instance variable for SQL_MASK, which contains all of the queries needed to set variables, etc. and add a new or update the existing record as needed.

Everything works beautifully, except when it comes to the actual database code.  I studied some existing code from the people before me, and this fits the syntax I saw them using.

Unfortunately, I can't get VB to stop throwing errors like this:

```
(15, 5) Microsoft VBScript runtime error: Object required: ''
```

Here is the relevant part of my code...

```
12 dim dbconn, connect
13 connect = "Driver={SQL Server};Server=XXX;Database=XXX;uid=XXX;pwd=XXX"
14 dbconn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
15 dbconn.Open connect
16 dbconn.Execute(SQL)
```

I couldn't really find documentation that I could make heads or tails of (I am hardware/user support through experience/training, programmer only through trial by fire).

Can someone tell me what I'm missing? I would appreciate any help!

Comment: You are most likely missing the `SET` in front of the `dbconn` in line 15. i.e. change it to `set dbconn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a set command on line 14 maybe that's it? The driver will depend on what type of machine you are running the script on.

```
dim dbconn, connect
connect = "Driver={SQL Server};Server=XXX;database=XXX;uid=XXX;pwd=XXX"
Set dbconn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
dbconn.Open connect
dbconn.Execute(SQL)
```

Comment: Knew it had to be something simple.  I'm used to using AutoIt but my job requires VBS :)